# Is it possible to have Testcafe remember an h1 or a text from a previous page so I can match/compare it in another page?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to do a smoke test on a web page and essentially if I can somehow get Testcafe to remember "Hello World" from page 1 and go to a User Profile to match that same element with the text "Hello World" then I can make it work for all the other cases I will have

I am currently using Testcafe in a mac environment. I tried selectText but it wouldn't work for me.

I expect when Testcafe clicks on a tab that says "Hello World" and on the next page it can match the title with the same time from the previous tab

Answer (score 3):

After you take DOM element you can take it's text using `textContent` property (see [doc](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/dom-node-state.html#members-common-across-all-nodes))

You can then save this text to variable and use it to compare with text on another page

```
const h1Text = await Selector("h1").textContent
```

Comment: That seemed to work! Thanks; I read through the documentation several times and I guess I missed that section; my Test failed but I think I know what's wrong. Are you a Testcafe guru? I have another TC related question

Comment: @DjKniteX - what is your question?  I'd just start a new 'thread' within StackOverflow...many people can help then.